# Output Matplotlib figure to EPS with text as text

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

This question is similar to below:
[Output matplotlib figure to SVG with text as text, not curves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34387893/output-matplotlib-figure-to-svg-with-text-as-text-not-curves)

Using matplotlib, I would like to output figures in EPS with not outlined texts such as
labels legends ticks and so on..

How can I do that?

Comment: I wonder if that is even possible.