# Output multiline text as a single svg text object with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34387893/output-matplotlib-figure-to-svg-with-text-as-text-not-curves) is useful to get labels as text objects in an svg exported from matplotlib.
However, if labels span several lines (when `\n` are inserted in labels) the different lines are output as different text objects within a group.

Is there any way to get them to be a single multiline text object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The reason matplotlib does this is because SVG `<text>` elements don't support automatic line wrapping.  So anything that wants to output multi-line text has to calculate the line wrapping itself.

The in-development SVG 2 spec does support auto line-wrapping ([see `inline-size`](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#text-InlineSize)). But, as far as I am aware, no browsers support that feature yet.